# Literature suggestion for understanding Gauge theory from the perspective of a Mathematician.

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

Can anyone please suggest **some good literature or references for understanding Gauge theory from the perspective of a mathematician (from the point of view of differential geometry)?** Being a Mathematics PhD student(differential geometry) I want the introduction mathematically as rigorous as possible.

> **Specially I want to understand the space of connections and the action of Gauge group on it.**

***My background is following:***

I have read Fibre bundles(principle G-bundles), Theory of Connections( Connection as distribution and as a Lie algebra valued 1-form, Local connection forms, Holonomy Theorem(Ambrose and singer), flat connections and some Affine Connections from ***Foundation of Differential Geometry(Kobayashi and Nomizu) Vol-1***, Characteristic Classes(Chern classes) from **Foundation of Differential Geometry(Kobayashi and Nomizu) Vol-2**, general theory of fibre bundles(Milnor's classification for principle bundles) from **Fibre Bundles Dale Husemoller** and I have some idea about basic Algebraic topology, cohomology theory and Category theory(**at level of a Masters student in Mathematics).**

Most of the literature I  came across in the internet I felt they were written from the perspective of a Physicist otherwise some research papers (which I felt too advanced for me now). Being  just a 1st year PhD student(differential geometry) it  would be really helpful for me if someone can refer (keeping in mind of my Mathematical background) a humble but Mathematically very rigorous literature in Gauge theory where action of Gauge group on the space of Connections is discussed in details.

> Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Some classic references (maybe it has been written something better since their publication I don't know) :

- about Instantons over 4D manifolds,  Donaldson & Kronheimer's "The Geometry of four manifold" and Uhlenbeck & Freed's "Instantons and four manifolds"
- about Seiberg-Witten,  J.W. Morgan's  "The Seiberg-Witten Equations And Applications To The Topology Of Smooth Four-Manifolds"